# Django: Otimizar buscas no Banco de Dados

Tags: python, django, mysqli, aplicação-web

Estou com dúvida no seguinte exercício:  A rota /albums/ está retornando uma listagem dos albuns com os artistas do album, porém em alguns de nossos clientes
que utilizam bancos armazenados em servidores próprios ela está muito lenta. Ao acompanhar as consultas SQL com um
profiler foi detectado que está sendo realizado muitas consultas no banco e isso está causando a lentidão

isso é que está representado na view:

```
class AlbumListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Album.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AlbumSerializer
```

existe alguma forma de otimizar essa queryset ?

Comment: Lucas, precisaria de mais informações sobre como esta essa model Album para ver se tem muitos relacionamentos, mas eu recomendaria dar uma olhada em no 
metodo select_related do Django - https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

Answer (score 0):

Fala aí, Dev. Acredito que já tenha encontrado uma boa solução para sua pergunta, mas percebi que ela não havia sido diretamente respondida e decidi compartilhar um artigo que já me ajudou.

Possivelmente, sua model Album deve ter um relacionamento com a model Artista. É provável que seja um relacionamento ManytoMany:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    artistas = models.ManyToManyField(Artista)
```

Se esse for o caso, vou apontar uma solução de diminua suas consultas ao banco.

```
class AlbumListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Album.objects.prefetch_related('artistas').all()
    serializer_class = AlbumSerializer
```

Independentemente do número de álbuns ou de artistas que o seu banco tiver, apenas 02(duas) consultas serão realizadas pelo Python. Uma para pegar os álbuns e outra para pegar os artistas. Contudo, usar filtros nas QuerySets pode ajudar no tráfego de dados úteis.

O artigo, que me ajudou no passado ainda está no ar: http://pythonclub.com.br/django-introducao-queries.html
Um artigo mais recente sobre otimização:
https://betterprogramming.pub/django-select-related-and-prefetch-related-f23043fd635d